# lumen5.6 - ReflectionException Class XXController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to create API with `Lumen 5.6.3`.
and got error like below.

```
ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\ListController does not exist
in Container.php line 767
```

In `web.php`, I wrote

```
$router->get('list', 'ListController@index');
```

And I have `ListController.php` in `app/Http/Controllers` directory.

I did `composer dump-autoload -o` and found there is `ListController.php` in `autoload_classmap.php`.

Now I have all codes in `web.php` without using controllers and it works.

```
$router->get('list', function(Request $request) {
   return response()->json(['dummy'=>'dummy']);
}
```

Any comments will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does the controller have a namespace?

Comment: Yes, ListController has `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` as lumen example shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a wrong value for `bootstrap/app.php`.

I set like the below.

`require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';`

After I modified this part like following, lumen became to able to call Controllers in App\Controllers.

`require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`